# Model relation with composite key

Tags: php, yii

I need help in creating a model relation to a table with composite key.
I have the following two models :

```
ModelOne (
    id, PRIMARY KEY
    parent_id,
    parent_type,
    ...
)
```

and

```
ModelTwo (
    parent_type,
    parent_id,
    ...
)
```

In ModelTwo I`ve already override the primary key:

```
public function primaryKey()
    {
        return array('parent_type', 'parent_id');
    }
```

How can I define a relation in ModelOne to get the related ModelTwo? (1 to 1 relation)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need this:

```
public function relations() {   
  return array(
    'two' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'ModelTwo', '', 'on'=>'t.parent_type=modelTwo.parent_type'),
  );
}
```

Comment: I think the solution is: 
    self::HAS_ONE,
    'ModelTwo', 
    array('parent_id' => 'parent_id', 'parent_type' => 'parent_type'),